# Let event handler listen for click on link the id of which is changed

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I have got a link with an id and listen for the click event. I have set up an event listener for a different id as well.

How can I fire the right events if I change the links id dynamically? ATM it will still use the old event listener despite the different id

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxmxxkm0/) is not working!

Any ideas?

HTML

```
<a href='#' id="button1">Click Me</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery('#button1').on('click',function(){
    jQuery('#result').show().html('Clicked on button 1!').fadeOut(1000);
    jQuery(this).attr('id','button2');
});
                 
jQuery('#button2').on('click',function(){
    jQuery('#result').show().html('Clicked on button 2!').fadeOut(1000);
    jQuery(this).attr('id','button1');
});
```

Comment: You should never change ID dynamically. Now to answer your question, read: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/  But basically, your logic is quite wrong, you should filter depending some condition inside an unique click handler

Comment: What is the problem with changing ids? I could as well leave the id and change the class - the problem would be the same for me.
I am loading additional javascript code on click and want to execute a newly loaded function when clicking the same element as before.
I'm not yet sure if listening for clicks on the parent would help

Comment: Ya, delegating event would definetaly help, see http://jsfiddle.net/wxmxxkm0/2/   And you shouldn't change IDs because there is absolutely no reason to do that when, in same time, there are many methods to change instead classes as e.g `toggleClass('class1 class2')`. In your example, this is not a big issue to switch IDs because you are doing it on only one element, but if you need to apply it to more complex example with many elements, this could bring you with duplicate IDs and then code could stop working as expected.

Comment: Ah sure, that's a quite obvious solution. And I can do this with classes as well, e.g. class 'a' and 'b' for #button: 
`jQuery(document).on('click', '#button.a', function () {});`
Can you please post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be just:

```js
    jQuery('#button1').on('click',function(){
        $(this).data('toggled', !$(this).data('toggled'));
        jQuery('#result').finish().show().html($(this).data('toggled') ? 'Clicked on button 1!' : 'Clicked on button 2!').fadeOut(1000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' id="button1">Click Me</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```

You shouldn't switch ID attribute for specific element in any case. If you have specific style to apply, then toggle a class instead.

Comment: Okay I see, it's not only about specific styles, but also about some functionality like ajax request etc. that are supposed to happen on click.
In fact it is even more complicated: On click I want to load new javascript code onto the page that handles the click on the link. Therefore, I have two event handlers on the page at the same time.
I thought the easiest way to differentiate between them would be to change the element's id!